# Ride Robot Framework IDE - Mac Interface Trouble

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I've just installed Ride editor on my Mac and I'm new to this. My python version is 3.9.4 on BigSur 11.4 and I'm using the dark mode theme.
I have trouble with the colors because I can barely see anything, only when something is selected. I've tried to change colors in the preferences but no luck.
I can't see the names of my files only when they are selected.

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk7Ua.png)

I can't even write simple text case because I can't see what I am typing because of that yellow background and characters are white. Only after enter or when it is selected you can see what is in the field.

[Test case fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/201y2.png)

I can't make dictionary nor the list variables. I can only define them and add them values directly in the script because that window with the fields on the left is to small and I can't stretch it.

[Dictionary Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt8Xa.png)

If someone has facing the same thing or has an idea or solution at least for part of it would be great because I am out of the ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed latest development from master (you probably did, so you can use with Python 3.9), you have options to change colors (and save and restore), from Tools->Preferences->General and for the Grid, Editor and Run tabs.

It would be nice to have those color settings files shared with the community. Please go to the [project page](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE) and create an issue with those settings, or communicate on our Slack.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I already tried to adjust colors in the Tools->Preferences for  the  Grid, Editor and Run tabs but with no luck. The general adjustment I can't find. Will go to the project page.

Comment: The General section, is only available on current development version, installed from master. It is version 2.0b2.dev3.